# Matlab - Compatibility in Different Editions

Tags: matlab, user-interface, compatibility

I am running a project on Matlab 2012Ra , which I have created some GUI via GUIDE, and it works great. Surprisingly, I tested it on the Newest edition (2013) and also on the oldest (2011Rb) . I found out that, on 2013 edition, functions were working great but GUI wasn't the same, which made a lot of difference and also that in 2011Ra edition, there was an error (!) in

```
 videoFrames = read(getImpl(obj), index); % function i used to read frames from a movie %
```

(In other two editions it was working fine!). So my question is, does matlab changes overall their compilers from different editions or am I missing something?

Comment: Always read the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) for each version. At the very end of the notes for each version there is a section titled "Functionality being removed or changed."

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks try pretty hard not to make things incompatible between releases, and when they know they're going to make some changes that will break existing code they try to announce it a few versions before they release, in order that you have a year or so to prepare any changes you might need to make.

But they do make improvements that sometimes introduce incompatibilities, and they do fix bugs that sometimes people didn't realise were bugs and were relying on - and sometimes, they accidentally break something without realising, or introduce a bug they didn't anticipate. When they do that, they will often post a workaround or fix on the support site.

If you have a particular problem with your code related to an incompatibility between releases, post it.